# Notepad++ removing double quotes and adding commas

Tags: notepad++

```
"000305"    "00202" "53H5"  08/29/2022 12:46:39 "40 Minutes"    "02"    "HELP RELATED"
```

I have this data, I want to get rid of the double quotes and a comma after each word in notepad++. Please help !

Output should be :

```
000305,00202,53H5,08/29/2022 12:46:39,40 Minutes,02,HELP RELATED
```

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^"|"$|("\h+"|"\h+|\h+")`
- Replace with: `(?1,)`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  ^"          # quote at the beginning of line
|           # OR
  "$          # quote at the end of line
|           # OR
  (           # start group 1
    "\h+"       # 1 or more horizontal spaces inside quotes
  |           # OR
    "\h+        # quote followed by 1 or more horizontal spaces
  |           # OR
    \h+"        # 1 or more horizontal spaces followed by quote
  )           # end group
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1         # if group 1 exists
  ,           # put a comma
)           # endif
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following the guidance in [How to replace spaces with commas](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17065/how-to-replace-spaces-with-commas/2), you should be able to:

1. Open the Replace dialog `C-h`.
2. Type in a `\x20+` character in the "Find what:" zone.
3. Type in a `,` character in the "Replace with:" zone.
4. Select the `Regular expression` search mode.
5. Click on the `Replace All` button.

In your case, it looks like you want to preserve spaces within the fields, so you may want to replace `"\x20+"` with `,` instead.

Comment: Have you tried it? This doesn't remove double quotes.

Comment: Oops. That was just a reading comprehension error.

Answer (score 0):

This will be 2 times replace.
First, open the Replace dialog box, then in "Find what:" type `"\s+"|\s*"\s*` and in "Replace with:" type `,` and click `Replace All`. **Remember to select `Regular Expression` in the `Search Mode`**
Second, again open the Replace dialog box and this time in "Find what:" type `^,|,$` and leave the "Replace with:" blank and click `Replace All`. This time as well **remember to select `Regular Expression` in the `Search Mode`**
This will give you your desired output.
Input:
`"000305"    "00202" "53H5"  08/29/2022 12:46:39 "40 Minutes"    "02"    "HELP RELATED"`
First output:
`,000305,00202,53H5,08/29/2022 12:46:39,40 Minutes,02,HELP RELATED,`
Second output:
`000305,00202,53H5,08/29/2022 12:46:39,40 Minutes,02,HELP RELATED`

Comment: This doesn't work when there are multiple lines, they all be joined in a single line.